# Updating the text property of a detailsview control in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

How can I update the text of a detailsview boundfield in edit or insert mode from a button click?

I have a detailsview edit / insert form and a FileUpload control  on the same page. Whilst in edit or insert mode I'd like to be able to upload a PDF and change one of the detailsview controls text to the PDF path.

Something like:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Insert)
    {
        DetailsView1.FindControl("attachment").text = FilePath;

    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can access the controls in DataBound event of DetailsView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should typecast the control you are searching for into the desired type of control, like:

```
TextBox Check=DetailsView1.FindControl("attachment") as TextBox;
```

then you should try to either get or set its value. Like:

```
Check.text="Something";
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Needed to convert it to a template field. Works fine now thanks.